# Secure Store Service not working and grayed out

Tags: 2010, windows-authentication, secure-store

I cannot get my Secure Store Service to work on my dev environment. I am trying to use a new external content type to render a SQL DB table in SharePoint (BDC).

When I visit Manage Service applications and Secure Store Service I am receiving the error:

*Cannot complete this action as the Secure Store Shared Service is not responding.*

- The ribbon is greyed out.
- I am logged in as the admin account

I have tried:

- I stopped and started Secure Store Service
- I stopped and started SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool in IIS
- I went to Administrative Tools – Local Security Policy and ensured admin account has Log on as a Service and I added the admin account to Log on as a batch job
- I ran IISRESET (I rebooted the machine a few times over the course of the last 24 as well)

I checked the services:

- Claims To windows Token Service is started
- Secure Store Service is started
- PerformancePoint Service is started

I checked BDC as well:

Central Admin - Application Management - Manage Service Applications – Business Data Connectivity Service.  I checked my external content type and checked object permissions.  All Authenticated Users was set with all permissions checked.  I set object permissions for the admin account as well.

Finally, Windows Authentication enabled and ASP.NET Impersonation enabled in IIS.  I checked the web.config and it matches.

I’m not sure what more to look at.  Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: any correlation ID or anything is ULS logs or event logs?

Comment: Nothing regarding secure store.  It doesn't show any correlation ID at all. Of course I do get errors regarding the anonymous login.

Comment: Error from Application logs: the secure store service application is not accessible, The full exception of the text is: The socket connection was aborted.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like issue with the SSL certs. You have to bind the correct cert with it.

- first get the thumbprint of SharePoint Service Cert from the Cert store.
- then delete the existing cert using this `netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0:32844`
- now register the cert properly. `netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0:32844 certhash=<thumbprint> appid=<appid> certstorename=SharePoint`

Read more [here](https://codeimprovements.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/reassigning-the-correct-ssl-certificate-to-sharepoint-2010-web-services-iis-site/) AND [THIS](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rhepworth/post/2010/01/07/reassigning-the-correct-ssl-certificate-to-sharepoint-2010-web-services-iis-site)

Also check this one:http://sensoft2000-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/10/error-security-token-service-is-not.html

Comment: +1 for the info.  I had not seen all of these articles.  Nonetheless, after attempting everything here, still no luck.